# RestAPI versioning through headers

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I'm trying to implement backward compatibility of API versioning . I'm searching end to end flow of API versioning through headers, could some one please give any sample link/project of this kinda implementation.

Comment: Question is (1) asking for off-site resources (sample links, project, ...) and (2) very broad. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: https://www.troyhunt.com/your-api-versioning-is-wrong-which-is/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some implementations put the version in the "Accept-version" header like:

```
Accept-version: v1
Accept-version: v2
```

Other put them in the more standard "Accept" header like so:

```
Accept: application/vnd.example.v1+json
Accept: application/vnd.example+json;version=1.0
```

Check out: https://restfulapi.net/versioning/

Then it's up to your code framework to get them.

Answer (score 0):

You can access header fields in a RestController like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public Demo get(@RequestHeader("Api-Version") String apiVersion)  {

}
```

Then you just have to check for the apiVersion.

Personally I prefer the version in the URL.